# Can't Figure Out How To Include All Worksheets When Hiding Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I finally give up after about 12 hours. I FINALLY figured out how to hide the columns properly, or at least I think it's working properly. Any feedback / corrections is welcome.

Can anyone tell me how to do this for all the worksheets (every day of the week) instead of just the one? I can't search anymore!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim entireRange As Range
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Fri")

Set entireRange = ws.Columns("AI:AN")

    entireRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Select Case ActiveSheet.Range("C4")

  Case "6"
      ws.Range("AJ:Am").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

  Case "7"
      ws.Range("AK:AM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

  Case "8"
      ws.Range("AL:AM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

  Case "9"
      ws.Range("AM:AM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

  Case "5"
      entireRange.Hidden = True

End Select
End Sub
```

Appreciate your help, and all the help you've given all the other people on here enabling me to get this far. Here's the file if that helps: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sSGSMCAo-4JrvLF0s81MxjC4dZ78RgPb

Comment: Will the change always occur on the same worksheet? Or, are you looking for the same functionality where an `On_Change` event is fired from each worksheet?

Comment: I guess I should have clarified. It's for scheduling movies in a theater. The theater it's going to says how many theaters they have and so I hide the rest to make it clean. Some of them have 5, 7, 10, etc. Does that answer your question?

Comment: So, when C4 in **Movies** worksheet changes, it should hide columns in MON-SUN worksheets?

Comment: Yes, Patrick. I had an issue with the one  I did unhiding some other columns, but I think I took care of that. This is all new to me. I've never used VBA before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want auto columns hide when cell C4 is changed on a worksheet (not just "Fri"), below code should do fine. Hope there is data validation on C4.

*Possible improvments:* The range to hide seems to be able to be calculated by the value in C4 instead of fixed by each value.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim entireRange As Range, hideRange As Range

    ' Assuming only monitor changes on cell C4 on the worksheet, not just "Fri"
    If Target.Address(0, 0) <> "C4" Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    Set entireRange = ws.Columns("AI:AN")
    entireRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Select Case CInt(Target.Value)
      Case 6
          Set hideRange = ws.Range("AJ:AM")

      Case 7
          Set hideRange = ws.Range("AK:AM")

      Case 8
          Set hideRange = ws.Range("AL:AM")

      Case 9
          Set hideRange = ws.Range("AM:AM")

      Case Else ' 5
          Set hideRange = entireRange
    End Select
    hideRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Set entireRange = Nothing
    Set hideRange = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE**: After getting the Excel file and knowing what the goal was, this will work great. Easy to add more theaters - change the `TheatersColumns` text.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Skip any changes unless it's cell 'Movies'!$C$4
    If Target.Address(0, 0) <> "C4" Then Exit Sub

    ' Columns from Theater 1 to the gap, change for expansion
    Const TheatersColumns As String = "AD:AN"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, MaxTheathers As Integer
    Dim entireRange As Range, hideRange As Range, GapColumn As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Make changes if it's not the caller worksheet
        If ws.Name <> Target.Worksheet.Name Then
            Set entireRange = ws.Columns(TheatersColumns) ' Columns from Theater 1 to the gap (#theaters+1)
            MaxTheathers = entireRange.Count - 1 ' Last col is blank (GapColumn)
            Set GapColumn = entireRange.Columns(MaxTheathers + 1)
            entireRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Set hideRange = ws.Range(GapColumn.Offset(, -(MaxTheathers - CLng(Target.Value))), GapColumn.Offset(, -1))
            ' Hide only when hideRange doesn't unclude GapColumn
            If Intersect(hideRange, GapColumn) Is Nothing Then
                hideRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
            Set hideRange = Nothing
            Set entireRange = Nothing
            Set GapColumn = Nothing
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it and don't think it worked. I added the file to the original post if that helps.

Comment: @Todd, See my update... it may be confusing to determine the calculated columns for hiding. But it's a lot more easy now. Make sure put it in **Movies** Sheet module.

Comment: Thanks so much, Patrick. I don't understand most of the words on the screen, but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of your days and loop through the sheets:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim entireRange As Range
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim day as string

Days = Array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")

For each day in Days
Set ws = wb.Sheets(day)
Set entireRange = ws.Columns("AI:AN")

entireRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Select Case ActiveSheet.Range("C4")

    Case "6"
       ws.Range("AJ:Am").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Case "7"
      ws.Range("AK:AM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

   Case "8"
       ws.Range("AL:AM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

   Case "9"
       ws.Range("AM:AM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Case "5"
     entireRange.Hidden = True
End Select
Next Day
```

End Sub

Comment: It doesn't like your Array line. I get an error with this as a help page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/syntax-error

Comment: @Todd there was a missing double quote. Fixed now. Try again